# Sonata PageBundle usage

Tags: symfony, bundle

I have trouble understanding how to use the [Sonata PageBundle](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/page/master), more exactly how / where to add blocks to a page so that content could be customized.
So far, when trying to add a block from the administration site, I got the "message_create_block_not_available" error as also described [here](http://groups.google.com/group/symfony2/browse_thread/thread/0a6e9646fc77370a).

What would be the correct way to add custom content to a page so that it can be manipulated with the PageBundle?

Comment: I tested it couple a days ago and concluded the bundle is not finished yet.

Comment: I could understand that adding blocks from the administration panel is not yet implemented, but I would assume that at least adding a block to a page in code should be possible. I guess it just needs some entries in config / template files. But from the documentation I cannot understand where...